# file.toURI() returning A Wrong value?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I work in a Java RCP application. I am doing the following lines of code:

```
File file = new File(location);
String filePath = file.toURI().toString();
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
desktop.browse((new URL(filePath)).toURI());
```

where location is a String.

When the value of location is: http://www.google.com,

```
file.toURI()
```

is appending "file:/C:/eclipse%203.7.2/eclipse/" to the value and hence it becomes 
file:/C:/eclipse%203.7.2/eclipse/http:/www.google.com

But when the value is: C:\Program Files,

```
file.toURI()
```

is not appending anything and returning the same value correctly.

Is there a limitation related to paths starting with http:// or something.
Does anyone have any idea on this ?

Comment: Google.com is not your desktop that's why it appeneded the location of eclipse, But c:\Program Files is part of your system, I think but not sure..Dont forgot You are using Desktop

Comment: Why are you creating a `File` with the string "http: //www.google.com"? That is not going to work. You're using "http: //www.google.com" as if it is a filename.

Comment: http://www.google.com was an example. I am trying to use a repository path. the path name starts with http://.
any path starting with http://, file:/C:/eclipse%203.7.2/eclipse/ is getting appended to the value.

Comment: `http` is not a "File". Just use the `URI` class directly instead.

Comment: I tried removing the file object and passing the string directly to the URI constructor. Worked well for me.
Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have 2 types of file locations: relative and absolute. When the location is something like `C:\User` in MS Windows or `/home` in Linux the location is absolute and there is no need to append something at the beginning of them! But when the location is `http://google.com` the program append your program location at the beginning of it.

I think you need to search about `URI` and `URL`. You used them incorrectly!

Answer (score 0):

java.io.File works with file paths not URLs.

So it transforms the supplied initialization parameters into the representation that is your local file system supports.

"http://" means nothing to your local file system, it's just a file name (well, wrong file name but anyway).

In the first case with "http://www.google.com" it does not see disk drive letter in the supplied value so it is considered as relative path and current working dir absolute path added as a prefix ("user.home" env var if I'm not mistaken).

In the second case, you added an absolute path "C:\Program Files". It sees disk drive letter inside and there is no sense to add anything as a prefix.